# Spring framework question

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Spring is well used these days. Are there any deficiencies of spring. Can it handle very heavy load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it can, but Google didn't bring back any citations to back up that claim.

I don't think that Spring would be the deciding factor in web app performance under a heavy load.  The app server and its configuration, the design of the application, etc. would have as much or more influence than the Spring framework.